# Nginx и поддомены

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, linux

Приветствую тебя, %username%. Я случайно столкнулся с проблемой реализации поддоменов в nginx + php_fpm. VirtualHosts вроде в рамках терминологии nginx'a. Так дело вот в чем:

Не очень то мне хотелось каждый раз создавать конфигурацию для следующего проекта, и собсна, я знал, что можно создать один конфиг для всех. Цель: хочу создавать /var/www/test.local, и переходя в браузере на http://test.local/ попадать туда, куда мне нужно.

собстна гуглением я написал примерный конфиг:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name local *.local;

        root /var/www/$host/;

        location ~ .php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/$host/$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

и сказать честно, это не работает. Мне кажется что дело в настройках dns, а точнее - там нет никакой записи о local, и *.local. Как быть, не понимаю, ибо днс сервер используется провайдерский. Была мысль `echo "127.0.0.1 local" > /etc/hosts` , но скорее всего это я бред какой то сморосил.

Как быть то ? :(

Comment: Проблема в том, что ответа не было, и был только комментарий :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте dnsmasq

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно решает мои проблемы)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете линукс, то никто не мешает вам поднять свой собственный ДНС сервер. Как было описано выше, это может быть и быстрый dnsmasq и полноценный типа  BIND. Перенастроить /etc/resolv.conf указав в нем
nameserver 127.0.0.1

и добавив нужные локальные зоны. Т.е. при запросе, если зона будет найдена на вашем локальном ДНС, то вы получаете резольвинг от него в нужный адрес, если не найдена, то передана провайдеру, и вы получите ответ уже от провайдерского днс.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я уже разобрался, как можно видеть ответом выше :) Использовал именно dnsmasq, и то что вы описали про настройку)